# Sort MySQL Query based on SUM

Tags: mysql, select

I struggle to get the right query:
There are two tables: `articles` and `orders`

I want to get a list from all the articles, but sorted by the times they were ordered. (Not only how many times the item was ordered, also including the amount)

`orders`: `id, article_id, amount`

`articles`: `id, description`

Example:

`articles`

```
1, apple
2, orange
3, lime
```

`orders`

```
1, 1, 5
2, 3, 1
3, 3, 2
4, 2, 1
```

Output should be:

```
1, apple,  5
3, lime,   3
2, orange, 1
```

Comment: This is a basic `join` and `group by` query.  The only subtlety I can readily see is that `key` is a reserved word, so it is a really bad choice for a column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic `join` and `group by` query, two fundamentals of the SQL language.  You should learn the language if you want to use databases effectively.

```
select a.`key`, count(o.id) as cnt, sum(amount)
from articles a left join
     orders o 
     on o.article_key = a.`key`
group by a.`key`
order by cnt desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.key, a.description, sum(amount) as sum_amount
from articles a
left join orders o on o.article_key = a.key
group by a.key, a.description
order by sum_amount desc
```